# Ionic Local Notification Every Week in specific hour not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, localnotification

**Plugin version:** cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"

**Platform:** Android

**OS version:** 6.0.1

**Cordova version (cordova -v):** 8.0.0

**Cordova platform version (cordova platform ls):** 7.0.0

**Plugin config:**

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
   id: notificationId,
   title: title,
   text: text,
   icon: "res://icon",
   smallIcon: "res://notification",
   color: '#000000',
   trigger: {
      firstAt: new Date(),
      every: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.WEEK
   }
});
```

**Ionic Version:** 4.0.1

If I try to use (in a test) `ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.MINUTE` without `firstAt` this works perfect but, defining the first notification date and using `ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.WEEK`, this not working. The docs of ionic native are very obscure for that and GitHub repo does not contain docs to that (ionic native interface change implementation structure).

Anyone using that in any case? After I discover an correct method to implement that, I am to submit a pull request in docs (Ionic Native) including orientations for that part.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? I need to implement basically the same thing in my app.

Comment: No sr., sorry. Now I trying to verify again this problem to find a solution. When I get that, I update this post to help you.